# Java: row's index does not changes when sorted

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, tablerowsorter

when I sort the row, the indexes of the rows doesn't seems to change at all - thus resulting the old row which was initially in that position before making any sort.
**here my code is**

```
DefaultTableModel  modelmachine = (DefaultTableModel) jTableMachine2.getModel();
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<>(modelmachine);
        jTableMachine2.setRowSorter(tr);
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(jTextField8.getText()));
```

Comment: `TableRowSorter` won't change the `TableModel`, it acts as a proxy between the model and the `JTable`.  See the [JavaDocs for `JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html) which discusses it and [`JTable#convertRowIndexToModel `](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int)) and [`JTable#convertRowIndexToView`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView(int)) to convert between the contexts

Answer (score 0):

Check out RowSorter's `convertRowIndexToModel` and `convertRowIndexToView` methods. You're probably getting the model index (the index in the model, which does not have the sorting applied), but you need the view index (the index of what you actually see).